# Mystery Segfault in between statements

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

Full disclosure: this is a homework assignment that I'm having bugs in.

I'm receiving mysterious intermittent segfaults - right after the `printf(...,pas_isin(thelist,5)` but BEFORE the next `printf`. Or at least that's what the output suggests - I guess it might be terminating somewhere inside `pas_isIn` and STDOUT isn't getting flushed.

```
printf("\n\nTesting isIn with 5 - should return 1");
printf("\npas_isIn returned %i",pas_isIn(thelist,5));

printf("\n\nTesting isIn with 10000 - should return 0");
printf("\npas_isIn returned %i",pas_isIn(thelist,10000));
```

Here's `pas_isIn()`:

```
//returns true if the given list contains the given value
int pas_isIn(int thelist[], int x) {
    int t;
    int length;
    //empty list dont' contain much of anything
    if (pas_isEmpty(thelist)) { return 0; }
    for (t=1; t <= length; t++) {
        if (thelist[t]==x) { return 1; }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thelist is an array, allocated with a size of 50 and at the time of the call contains around four values. The first value in thelist is the number of values in the array. Any ideas?

Comment: length is not initialized

Comment: I can't figure out why anyone would downvote you. The question is on topic. You showed your code, you explained your error, you asked for help. You admitted it was homework.  I'm going to upvote you just to balance the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`length` is not initialized in your code, it seems that you stored the length of the array in it's first element, so this should do it

```
//returns true if the given list contains the given value
int pas_isIn(int thelist[], int x) {
    int t;
    int length;
    length = thelist[0];
    //empty list dont' contain much of anything
    if (pas_isEmpty(thelist)) { return 0; }
    for (t=1; t <= length; t++) {
        if (thelist[t]==x) 
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

a not initialized variable of type `int` may contain any value, it could be too large for your `thelist` array.

Comment: Actually I meant thelist[0]. But yeah, that'd be it. Durp.

Comment: In this code `x` would be one more than the length of the list, since you write `t <= x`

Comment: No, x is the value being searched for.